# Access SQL Crosstab Function SELECT TOP 1

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I am calculating waste based on an administered amount corrected using a correction factor read from a table. The structure of the tables with some sample data is below:

RMP Administrations:

```
Nuclide      Product          MBq      Date Given
-------------------------------------------------
Tc-99m       Pertechnetate    700      2018/01/01
I-131        NaI              399      2018/02/01
I-131        NaI              555      2018/01/01
I-123        MIBG             181      2018/01/01
I-123        NaI              29       2018/01/03
```

WasteFactors

```
Nuclide    Product     MinActivity     MaxActivity    Factor
------------------------------------------------------------
Tc-99m     *                                          0.3
I-123      *                           150            0.3
I-123      *           150                            1
I-123      MIBG                                       0.6
I-131      *           400                            0.5
I-131      *                           400            1
```

So this table is complex, but it is the best way I can think of to represent the correction factors in a table. Nuclide is matched first, then if product matches that correction factor is used, finally we check the activity (MBq) against the Min / Max columns to decide. We then use this factor along with the activity to determine the waste using the following SQL

```
SELECT
  Nuclide,
  [Date Given] AS Given,
  (SELECT TOP 1
    Factor
  FROM WasteFactors
  WHERE [RMP Administrations].Nuclide = WasteFactors.Nuclide
  AND [RMP Administrations].Product LIKE WasteFactors.Product
  AND (WasteFactors.MinActivity IS NULL
  OR WasteFactors.MinActivity > [RMP Administrations].MBq)
  AND (WasteFactors.MaxActivity IS NULL
  OR WasteFactors.MaxActivity <= [RMP Administrations].MBq)
  ORDER BY WasteFactors.Nuclide ASC, WasteFactors.Product DESC)
  AS Waste
FROM [RMP Administrations] WHERE NOT [RMP Administrations].Nuclide IS NULL AND NOT [RMP Administrations].MBq IS NULL
```

So this achieves what we require by sorting the Factor table so that factors with a product name appear before factors which apply to all other products, so with the data above 'I-123 MIBG' is checked before 'I-123 *'.

so, running this SQL along with the data above should return the following:

```
Nuclide   Given          Waste
--------------------------------------------------------
Tc-99m    2018/01/01     0.3         (All Tc-99m is 0.3)
I-131     2018/02/01     1           (Activity <=400)
I-131     2018/01/01     0.5         (Activity >400)
I-123     2018/01/01     0.6         (Product is MIBG)
I-123     2018/01/03     0.3         (Not MIBG, <150)
```

with that factor used as `MBq * (SELECT TOP 1...) AS Waste` in the real code. So... this works fine; and I can summarise by data annually with a normal `SUM(Waste)`, `GROUP BY Nuclide` and `WHERE Year(Given)=[Enter Year]`. My issues begin when I try to use this in the following crosstab query:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Year] Short;
TRANSFORM SUM(T.MBq *
  (SELECT TOP 1
    Factor
  FROM WasteFactors
  WHERE T.Nuclide = WasteFactors.Nuclide
  AND T.Product LIKE WasteFactors.Product
  AND (WasteFactors.MinActivity IS NULL
  OR WasteFactors.MinActivity >T.MBq)
  AND (WasteFactors.MaxActivity IS NULL
  OR WasteFactors.MaxActivity <= T.MBq)
  ORDER BY WasteFactors.Nuclide ASC, WasteFactors.Product DESC)
)
SELECT T.Nuclide
FROM [RMP Administrations] AS T
WHERE Year(T.[Date Given])=[Enter Year]
GROUP BY T.Nuclide
PIVOT Format(T.[Date Given],"mm - mmm");
```

giving the error 'Access does not recognise T.Nuclide as a valid field or....'. I can't see an error in my SQL, and don't see why it should not work as written, I have tried making a VBA function to calculate the waste amount `SUM(GetWaste(Nuclide, Product,MBq))`, with the function running the same SQL as above in a recordset however then my query is too complex to be evaluated.

Does anyone have any ideas on where I have gone wrong with my crosstab query, how I can restructure my WasteFactors to make then easier to query, or is this just too complex to try to do in SQL and I should just do it in VBA it instead?

The real data set is ~1000 records, spanning multiple months, I would like to change Table and Col names to something not crap but I didn't create the database. Expected output for above data would be:

```
Nuclide    01 - Jan    02 - Feb
-------------------------------
Tc-99m     210
I-131      277.5       399
I-123      117.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a subquery in a `TRANSFORM` clause in that way afaik.

Use a subquery in your `FROM` clause multiplying that subquery with `MBq`. Then only use a plain aggregate in the `TRANSFORM` clause

Sample, probably needs refining:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Year] Short;
TRANSFORM SUM(TransformField)
SELECT R.Nuclide
FROM (SELECT *, 
Mbq * (SELECT TOP 1
    Factor
  FROM WasteFactors
  WHERE T.Nuclide = WasteFactors.Nuclide
  AND T.Product LIKE WasteFactors.Product
  AND (WasteFactors.MinActivity IS NULL
  OR WasteFactors.MinActivity >T.MBq)
  AND (WasteFactors.MaxActivity IS NULL
  OR WasteFactors.MaxActivity <= T.MBq)
  ORDER BY WasteFactors.Nuclide ASC, WasteFactors.Product DESC) As TransformField
 FROM [RMP Administrations] T
) AS R
WHERE Year(R.[Date Given])=[Enter Year]
GROUP BY R.Nuclide
PIVOT Format(R.[Date Given],"mm - mmm");
```

Comment: The SELECT runs fine by itself, returning exactly what I would expect; however when inside the crosstab Access gives me '..database Engine does not recognise 'T.Nuclide' as a valid field name or expression'

Comment: @Sam Weird, you can usually work around that by storing the `FROM` subquery in a separate query.

Comment: Tried that too, same result. Seems like I may be reaching Access' limitations with weird requests...

Comment: Try applying your earlier workaround (the `GetWaste` VBA function) to this solution

Comment: That did the trick! Annoying to have to have a VBA function for what seems like it should be possible in just SQL, but if it's woking im happy

Comment: Usually, these problems are caused by the optimizer recombining your query incorrectly, and I often can get them to disappear with a lot of trial and error. Things like swapping `TOP 1` for `First()` may get you to a non-vba solution. But glad you got it working.

Comment: My VBA function gives me the bonus of being able to catch input errors anyway (which should have been fixed in the first place, havent got that far yet), such as 'Tc-99m ' and defaulting the factor to 1 if nothing is found in my factor table (worst case to complete waste the figures).